# Как вычислить правильно расстояние по координатам?

Tags: геолокация, координаты

Нахожу координаты городов. С этим вопросов нет. Получил координаты одного и другого города. Найти расстояние необходимо теперь. Нашел в разные способы, почему то погрешность в этих вычислениях выходит от 15 до 200 км в сравнении с гуглом. Вот последний код:

```
public static double distFrom(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
    double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
                    Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    double dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);
    double dist2 = (float) (earthRadius * c)/1000;
    String my_distance = String.valueOf(dist2).substring(0,3);

    tvAdress2.setText("~ " + my_distance +" км");



    return dist;
}
```

Comment: Судя по коду вы считаете Землю шаром. Подозреваю, что гугл использует большее точную модель [WGS 84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) в которой земля эллипсоид.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать класс Location.

```
Location.distanceBetween(oldPosition.latitude, oldPosition.longitude,
            newPosition.latitude, newPosition.longitude, results);
```

Для более точного результата можно попробовать утилиту от Google. У этого решения есть свои недостатки поэтому решайте в зависимости от ваших требований.

```
SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(latLngFrom, latLngTo)
```

Для нее необходимо добавить зависимость

```
 implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.2.3'
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое. Щас буду пробовать.

Comment: Вот наверно надо точнее описать проблему ))) Location.distanceBetween()... Не дает точные данные, все способы, если я правильно понял считают расстояние не по дороге, а по самому короткому пути на прямую. А мне же нужно чтобы точно было. Все что было в интернете перерыл, но так ничего и не помогло. Первый раз с этим работаю.

Comment: тогда используй https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Буду разбираться ))

Comment: Подскажите, этот сервис от гугл бесплатный?

Comment: зависит от количество использований, какое то количество запросов бесплатное. Для маленького проекта хватит

Comment: Понял спасибо!!!